# Java var from statement doesn't save

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I can't save var stop so it can stop for cycle. I just need when tryOpen is true to exit that method and stop doing recursion.

```
    public void moznosti(char [] arr, String pr, int a, int b) {
        boolean stop = false;
        if (b == 0) {
            char [] heslo = pr.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < heslo.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(heslo[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (tryOpen(heslo)) {
                stop = true;
                System.out.println("END");
            }
            return;
        }
        if (stop == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                String tmp = pr+arr[i];
                moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1);
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  However, if you are thinking that you can set `stop` in one recursive call, and that the other recursive calls will be able to see it, you're wrong.  There's a separate local variable `stop` for each recursive invocation.  Consider using a `return` to communicate between recursive invocations.

Comment: Maybe you need `stop` to not be a local variable? could be a return value.

Comment: you mean to not have void but boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Stop is a local variable here. If you make it a static global variable it will work, but note that you will have to set it to false before every time you call moznosti.

The above will work, but it isn't that good of a practice.

The best method would be to make your function return true when it succeeds. Then you can check success before making any more recursive calls:

```
    if (b == 0) {
        char[] heslo = pr.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < heslo.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(heslo[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (tryOpen(heslo)) {
            System.out.println("END");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                String tmp = pr + arr[i];
                if (moz(arr, tmp, a, b - 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, this is what I did now it's working but it is slow...

```
    public boolean moznosti(char [] arr, String pr, int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        char [] heslo = pr.toCharArray();
        if(tryOpen(heslo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            String tmp = pr+arr[i];
            if (moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}